# Is a 6 core i5 sufficient for light virtualisation and cpu heavy games?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, gaming

Soon I'll be building my first desktop pc with the following specifications
Intel core i5 8400/8600 (not quite certain which locked i5) 
16gb 2666 mhz ram
GTX 1060 6gb
I would like to play cpu heavy games and do some light virtualisation from time to time (1 virtual machine at  a time) , I would use virtualbox for my virtualisation work , is 6 threads enough for this task?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your tolerance is.  How much this affects your game(s) will depend on exactly which game(s) you use.  In all likelihood, this will work for lots of software.  However, whether it works well enough to be a satisfying experience will depend on just how flexible you are(n't).

If you don't mind slower virtualization, this might be just fine for you.  If you have experienced faster performance and will be bothered by slower performance, you may find the experience to be highly irritating.  So, at least some of the acceptability might be a detail that is rather unique to you.

Comment: For games I'd just like 1.5-2 years of 30-60 fps at 1080p , for vms  I have only experienced virtualisation on a 4core/8 thread laptop with 8gb ram . I just need a machine for a while so I can save enough money for an alienware laptop.